# Появились ли в PHP8 потоки

Tags: php, многопоточность

Появились ли в PHP8 потоки, если да, то как их использовать?

Comment: это оно https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.thread.php ?

Comment: это расширение написанное левыми разработчиками

Comment: а что же их тогда на оффициальном сайте выложили? Вообще то потоки в пхп существовали ещё с незапамятных времен. Просто делаете ещё один скрипт и через любимый http клиент открываете. Правда чуточку рулить сложно, но решаемо.

Comment: @KoVadim, а что ж тогда мелкософт при выпуске винды не смог реализовать TCP/IP протокол, и скомуниздил открытые линуксоидные исходники и реализовал на них драва, а через почти 30 лет открыто об этом сказал, да мол мы тогда так поступили ::))) Мол извиняемся, не смогли мы реализовать свое.

Comment: не линуск исходники, а BSD, и лицензия позволяля. Но только при чем это здесь - я вообще не понимаю. Ещё и так грубо